# Admin menu layout for my nodes

Tags: routes, theming

I have a simple question: i need to use the layout and structure of drupal admin menu for my own nodes.
I need to replicate the structure and the feeling of admin menu and the page design for my nodes, how can i do that?
I need to replicate exactly the way the admin menu acts and feel on the body part of the site, so with two columns, groups of subtopic for each main topic, links listing for each level and my nodes as leafs of this structure.
Since this is already done on the admin menu, it should be possible to do it also with my own nodes, but how?
I am using Drupal 6

Comment: When you say admin menu, do you actually mean the Seven admin theme that ships with Drupal 7 plus the toolbar?

Comment: I am using Drupal 6, and i talk about the page you see when you click on "Administer" and you get the body with all the admin sections and sub sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts are that you could use views to list various categories of nodes. And to have a similar layout structure, I haven't used it but I think Panels might help.

An alternative to Panels which I have used in the wonderful [homebox](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://drupal.org/project/homebox&ei=LllCT529GofY8gPy-sCSCA&usg=AFQjCNE0LdzLDZq5mgMui1vGQhvtIpiYfA) module

Comment: Yes this is my actual implementation so far, but the result can't keep up to the look & feel of Administration page, and the panels are really hard to maintain if one of my users what to add something. It feels weird to me because if the administration is shown in that way, there should be functions somewhere that do this job